# How can infinity be an accumulation point?

Tags: analysis, infinity

> Let $(a_n)_{n∈\mathbb N}$ be a set in $\mathbb R$. For every $r ∈ \mathbb R$ exits an accumulation point $b ∈ R \cup \{{−\infty} \}$ of $(a_n)_{n∈\mathbb N}$ with $ b < r$ .  ($\pm \infty$ are allowed as accumulation points)
>
> Show, that $-\infty$ is an accumulation point of $(a_n)_{n∈\mathbb N}$.

I can't wrap my head around this: An accumulation point is a point of a set, which in every yet so small neighborhood (of itself) contains infinitely many points of the set, right?

If (in my case) $-\infty$ is an accumulation point, then we could find a point of the set, that is finitely distant from infintity?!

Comment: What are the open sets of infinity in whatever space you're dealing with?

Comment: So, you need a notion of "neighborhood of $-\infty$" to understand this.  Obviously, the usual "distance" is not the way to get such neighborhoods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which points of a metric (or topological) space are accumulation points depends on which metric (or topology) you are using.  In the case of $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$, the usual metric $d(x,y)=\vert x-y\vert$ is not going to work, since it is not a metric on this space.

Since you have tagged the question as *analysis* rather than *topology*, I'll assume that you don't want to work in an explicitly topological framework.  So instead, we use a sort of work around:

> A sequence $\langle x_n\vert n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ converges to $\infty$ if for every $M$ there is a natural number $N$ such that $$\forall n>N \, (x_{n}>M).$$

In this case, the idea of getting "close to infinity" is therefore expressed as "gets arbitrarily large".

Similarly:

> $\infty$ is an accumulation point of the sequence if for every real $M$ there is some $n$ such that $M<x_{n}<\infty$.

Note that if the sequence does not take the value $\infty$, this is equivalent to the sequence being unbounded above.  Note also that for any $M$, there must in fact be infinitely many such $n$s.

Convergence to $-\infty$, and the property of having $-\infty$ as an accumulation point are defined analogously.

---

So, you have a sequence $\langle a_{n}\vert n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ which has arbitrarily small accumulation points.  To show that $-\infty$ is also an accumulation point, you just need to show that it is unbounded below.  But this is straightforward: for every $M<0$, there is an accumulation point $b<(M-1)$, and so the sequence contains a term below $b+1$ (or $b+\varepsilon$ if you prefer, so long as $\varepsilon>0$). Thus $M$ is not a lower bound for the sequence.  Since $M$ is arbitrary, the sequence has no lower bounds, and therefore has $-\infty$ as an accumulation point.

Answer (score 4):

We use it in two different ways, that result in the same thing.  Either you are working in the extended reals, $\Bbb R \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$ and define all intervals of the form $[-\infty,x)$ and $(y,\infty]$ to be open.  Then $-\infty$ is an accumulation point of the sequence iff every open set containing $-\infty$ contains at least one element of the sequence.  The elements do not have to be "a finite distance" from $-\infty$, they just need to be "close" in the sense of being in open sets. That means whatever number I give you, there are elements of the sequence that are more negative.

The other approach is to continue working in $\Bbb R$ and to *define* "having an accumulation point at $-\infty$" (even though $-\infty$ is not part of our set) as having elements that are more negative than any value I give you.

Comment: So the acc-pt-definitions are not the same?

Comment: They result in the same sequences having accumulation points at infinity.  Since they operate in different spaces, they are not really the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the thing: when you add the points $\pm \infty$ into the real line, your space is no longer a metric space.

In particular, when we consider two points $x,y \in (-\infty,\infty)$, it makes sense to talk about the "distance between them", i.e. $|x - y|$.  In this case, it makes sense to talk about decreasing the "size of a neighborhood" because each point in a neighborhood about $x$ has a distance from $x$, which we can say is less than some radius $r$.

When we extend the line by adding $\pm \infty$, it no longer makes sense to talk about the distance of any two points.  In particular, we would have to say that every $x \neq \infty$ is "infinitely far away" from infinity, so no value of $|x - \infty|$ makes sense.

In order to deal with this, we extend our definition of open sets, and our definition of an accumulation point to handle this space which is only a "topological" space since it is no longer a metric space.  We say that an open neighborhood of $\infty$ is a set of the form $(a,\infty]$, and that $[-\infty,a)$ is an open neighborhood of $- \infty$.

We can say that *any* point $x$ in our metric space is an accumulation point of a set $S$ if *every* neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains a point in $S$ other than $x$.  So, $\infty$ is an accumulation point of $S$ if $(a,\infty]$ contains a (finite) member of $S$ for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Note that applying this definition to a finite $x \in \mathbb{R}$ gives you the usual notion of an accumulation point, since each neighborhood of radius $\frac 1n$ must contain a point in $S$ other than $x$.

Answer (score 1):

This means that, for any n and x, there are at least n points greater than x.

Just make n and x as large as you want.

For example, consider the positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting $b_n=\arctan a_n$  because $f:\mathbb R \to \left(-\frac {\pi}2,\frac {\pi}2\right)$ is a continuous function which has a continuous inverse. Everything then becomes nicely finite. This is a bit of a cheat, but is one way you might be able to visualise what is going on.