# Can an unbounded set have a closure?

Tags: general-topology

I'm wondering if a closure of a set can be unbounded. I know that a closure is the union of a set $A$ and the set of $A$'s boundary points. But can a closure be unbounded if $A$ is unbounded?

Does $A$ have a closure if it is unbounded? Then the closure is just $A$, right? But would $\mathbb{R}$ have a closure that includes $-\infty$ and $\infty$?

Thank you in advance, kind stranger!

Comment: Do you know the definition of the closure of a set? Do you know $A\subset \overline{A}$ ? Do you know that the superset of an unbounded set is unbounded? (REMARK: boundedness works if there is a notion of distance)

Comment: Every set has a closure - the intersection of all closed sets containing it.

Comment: And we know such closed sets exist because the entire space is classed as a closed set (just as the empty set is an open set).

Comment: Example.  In $\mathbb R$, the rationals are dense.  That is, the closure of $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R$.  Note that $\mathbb Q$ is unbounded.  Think about this: what is the boundary of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: Got it. So the closure of an unbounded set, such as $\mathbb{R}$, is $\mathbb{R}$. And responding to GEdgar, the boundary of $\mathbb{Q}$ is also the reals--aka included in the closure

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, $A \subseteq \overline{A}$, its closure.

Consequently, it is natural to say that if $A$ is unbounded, its closure must also be.

> **Exercise:** If $\overline{A} = A \cup \partial A$, how do we know that $A \subseteq \overline{A}$?
>
> **Exercise:** To look at this more formally, define for a subset $S$ of a metric space $(M,d)$,
> $$
> \operatorname{diam}(S) := \sup_{x,y \in S} d(x,y)
> $$
> and show that
> $$
> S \subseteq T \implies \operatorname{diam}(S) \le \operatorname{diam}(T)
> $$

However, the closure need not be equal to $A$. Consider the case of $A = (0,\infty)$, which is unbounded but with closure $[0,\infty) \ne (0,\infty)$.

> **Exercise:** Show that, indeed, $0$ is in the closure.
>
> **Exercise:** Show that the closure of any set is a closed set. Naturally the above example comes almost-immediately, since you will have a set that is open, but a closure which is closed. (Of course, a set can be both open and closed, called clopen, so this doesn't *immediately* give counterexamples, but it motivates potential areas to check.)

The closure of a set somewhat depends on the space in which it is living. If the "grander" metric space you are working in is $\mathbb{R}$ (under the usual distance), then $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, if you are working within the extended reals, $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$, then the closure of $\mathbb{R}$ does include the infinities. [Some relevant discussion here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777031/how-can-infinity-be-an-accumulation-point)